# Django Models - Foreign Key of different objects types that share a common base class

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following conceptual design in mind for one of my models.

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...

class B(A): #Inherits A
    fieldA = ...
    fieldB = ...

class C(A): #Inherits A
    fieldC = ...
    fieldD = ...

class D(models.Model):
    field = models.ForeignKey(A) #Here lies the problem, should store B or C
```

Given the models above, **I'd like to store a foreign key to either B or C in D but not both**.

I tried setting the Meta class property of A to abstract but that doesn't allow a ForeignKey relationship to A. I **do not** want to ever have an instance of A that isn't B or C, but if necessary, I can restrict this behavior with the save signal.

Is there an easier design that would allow me to store a foreign key from a list of types where all classes inherit from a common base?

Comment: Can you think of a case where you could make A abstract, have an intermediary T then have B, C and D all inherit from T. Or perhaps extend B,C and D from a concrete A. See this same question which is somewhat old http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114767/django-model-inheritance-and-foreign-keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two options:

1. Use a [generic relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1) in your `D` class instead of a foreign key.
2. If you don't need to filter `D` using specific fields from `B` or `C` you could continue with the approach you have now, but add a method to `D` that would retrieve the child class of `field`:

   ```
   class D(models.Model):
       field = models.ForeignKey(A)

       def get_field(self):
           try:
               return self.field.b
           except B.DoesNotExist:
               pass
           try:
               return self.field.c
           except C.DoesNotExist:
               pass
   ```

   This definitely has some performance implications and as you said in your post, you would have to manually ensure that every instance of `A` has a `B` or `C` subclass. Obviously this approach doesn't scale well if you are going to have `n` number of subclasses.

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one, currently I've implemented what you described in 2, I'm just very uncomfortable with the code.

Comment: Another option to make it more scalable would be to add a field to your `A` class (possibly a foreign key to `ContentType`) that would hold the meta data for the type of subclass. Then you wouldn't have to try them all.