# Django: Use different serializers for different (inherited) models in one endpoint

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have this models (for ilustration only):

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Person(Customer):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_lenght=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    # More data related to a person

class Company(Customer):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # More data related to a company
```

As you can see, I can have two "types" of customers, but they are both "customers" (I think this is a textbook example of inheritance). Everything works fine at the database level, but now I need to create an endpoint that will "dinamically" show the customer data based on which "type" of customer it is. Something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "company_name": "Big buck"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "first_name": "Jane",
        "last_name": "Doe"
    }
]
```

When working within my project, I use things like:

```
customer = Customer.objects.get(pk=100)
if hasattr(customer, 'person'):
   pass # Do some stuff
elif hasattr(customer, 'company'):
   pass # Do some other stuff
# Do common stuff related to both customer 'types'
```

So far, I've managed to work around by using different endpoints for "Person" and "Company" customers, but now I need to get both "types" of customers in a single endpoint. And I can't figure out how to write a serializer to get this!

Looking around I found [this example for using polymorphic models](https://www.merixstudio.com/blog/polymorphic-models-django/), however, since the project is quite big now, I'd like to keep things as "vanila" as possible. So my specific questions are:

1. Is there a way to create a "polymorphic" serializer using the above model definition?
2. If `django-polymorphic` (and `django-rest-polymorphic`) are the way to go, will using them break the functionallity?

Comment: is there some issue in using ```to_representation``` [method](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/) in serializer to achieve what you want?

Comment: You could've used ForeignKey in both classes instead and then do something sneaky with @property that would've returned you result [the way you need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114767/django-model-inheritance-and-foreign-keys).

Comment: @shivankgtm no... let me try it... if you have any pointers, I'd be thankful if you posted them :)

Comment: Hi @Barranka is it solved? in your serializer class you can override a ```to_representation``` method and then output a costom dictionary. in this function you can make queries etc.